# Assignment between pointers of different types is working and I dont know why

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv

I am a computer vision engineer and use the OpenCV library a whole lot. I often work with raw data of type `unsigned short` and have to assign it to `cv::Mat` object of OpenCV.

This `cv::Mat` object has a field called data, and this field is of type `unsigned char*` regardless of the type of the data.

So, what I do to assign `unsigned short*` data to the `unsigned char*` Mat.data is the following:

```
// Obtain raw data from the hardware
const unsigned short* rawData = engine->getRawData();

// Create Mat with right dimensions and of type 16 Bit unsigned and 1 channel (unsigned short)
cv::Mat Test = cv::Mat::zeros(480, 640, CV_16UC1);

// Assign data by casting rawData to unsigned char* type
Test.data = (unsigned char*) rawData;

// Convert Test to 8Bit unsigned so I can visualize it
Test.convertTo(irIm, CV_8UC1);
```

I use this method in a lot of situations and it works fine, but I never really understood why it works. I have a block of data of type unsigned short, and then I just cast it to `unsigned char*` and the program doesn't crash and no data is lost.

Can anyone help me understanding this?

EDIT:

Regarding the answers I got. 
I understand that the data will still be valid but interpreted differently, but it still does not make sense in my head.

Imagine I have the following short: 0010000100001000 . Now, I used a calculator to realize that this short represents 8456 in decimal. If then I interpret this as unsigned char, I will read it as two bytes, then I have 00100001 byte and then 00001000, which in no way represent the previous short value.

So my question still stands. The only thing that makes sense in my head is that OpenCV is somehow expecting these casts and will internally transform data so it doesn't lose meaning.

Comment: If your system has 2byte `short`, 1byte `unsigne char`, and you have an array of `short`, casting it to `unsigned char *` will let you access each byte of the shorts separately. Nothing else. Ie. you have twive as much `char`s than `shorts`,

Comment: If the data format fits the bill, what could go wrong?

Comment: I start with an array of 640*480 unsigned shorts. This array, obviously needs 640*480*sizeof(short) of space in memory. Then I just cast it to (unsigned char*). At this point I have an array with the size of 640*480*sizeof(unsigned char). 
This new array needs two times less space in memory and the data is not corrupted at all? How come?

Comment: No no no ;-) You cast a pointer -- the data is not touched nor changed. The "CV_16UC1" arg to `zeros()` seems to indicate 16 bit data from opencv's point of view which fits what `getRawData()` returns, if a short on your system has 16 bits.

Comment: `At this point I have an array with the size of 640*480*sizeof(unsigned char)` With usual variable sizes: no, you´ll have twice as much chars,

Answer (score 1):

People usually define raw bytes buffers as `unsigned char*`, because `unsigned char` is semantically a byte. A little better probably would be to use standardized integer type such as `uint8_t`, but both are seen.

Casting from one pointer type to another just changes the *interpretation* of the data it points to. It does not touch the data itself.

A similar situation is with `void*` sometimes people use this type to pass around buffers of unspecified content. With `void*`, however, you cannot use standard syntax for pointer arithmetics, internally such pointers are often cast to an appropriate type (or treated as separate bytes).

Answer (score 0):

the `data` field is a pointer to the matrix data.

it is expected in `(unsigned char*)`. You can cast a pointer of different type to `(unsigned char*)`. Still they point to the same memory address where your `rawData` are stored in.

But the important thing is when you create the matrix you specify the data type to be `CV_16UC1`. (one element is 16bit and unsigned. see [Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#mat-depth)).

So if in your machine a `short` is of 2 bytes then `(unsigned short*)` can be casted to `(unsigned char*)` and still the matrix is valid.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has a *memory model* that considers computer memory as byte-addressible:

> The memory available to a C++ program consists of one or more sequences of contiguous bytes. Every byte has a unique address.

-- C++ Standard, **[intro.memory]**/1

For historical reasons, rather than having a `byte` type to access bytes of memory byte-wise, C++ uses the *character types* `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char`:

> The *object representation* of an object of type `T` is the sequence of `N` `unsigned char` objects taken up by
>   the object of type `T`, where `N` equals `sizeof(T)`.

-- ibid., **[basic.types]**/4

That means that it is always legal to access program memory by casting a data pointer to `unsigned char *`.